# "Estas são as primeiras perguntas que temos que fazer-nos"

Tags: pronomes

Esta frase não me soa bem, mas não consigo explicar porquê. Eu diria:

> Estas são as primeiras perguntas que temos que fazer a nós próprios.

A seguinte também não me parece possível:

> *Estas são as primeiras perguntas que temos que fazer-nos a nós próprios.

Por outro lado, se não for reflexivo:

> Estas são as primeiras perguntas que eles têm de fazer-nos.

Com outros verbos, não vejo nenhum problema:

> A primeira coisa que temos de fazer é lavar-nos.
>   A primeira coisa que fizemos foi destruir-nos a nós mesmos.

Nestas construções, o pronome reflexo *nos* é mesmo obrigatório; a seguinte frase não é possível:

> *A primeira coisa que fizemos foi destruir a nós mesmos.

A minha intuição está correta? Porque é que não posso usar o *nos* (ou pelo menos não devo) neste caso, quando noutras circunstâncias é obrigatório?

<del>P.S.: preferia não entrar numa discussão ênclise vs. próclise; o leitor pode substituir mentalmente "fazer-nos" por "nos fazer" se preferir.</del>

Comment: good question.  I'd like to hear what grammarians have to say about it.

Comment: Também gostei. Senão não teria respondido. Mas não posso votar: hoje esgotei os meus votos.

Comment: O teu P.S. não faz sentido: podes usar o _nos_, só que no lugar certo. Num dos exemplos o _nos_ é redundante, mas essa redundância está legitimada pelo uso.

Comment: @Jacinto És capaz de ter razão. Vou então rasurá-lo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A frase do título não soa bem e não é gramatical, por causa do **que fazer-nos**: a conjunção **que** pede a próclise.  A alternativa gramatical mais próxima é pois:

> (1) Estas são as primeiras perguntas que temos **que nos fazer.**

A segunda já está bem:

> (2) Estas são as primeiras perguntas que temos **que fazer a nós próprios**.

A terceira está mal pela razão anterior, a conjunção **que** pede a próclise:

> (3) Estas são as primeiras perguntas que temos **que nos fazer a nós próprios.**

É claro que **nos + nós próprios** é um pleonasmo, mas é [pleonasmo legítimo](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/enganarmo-nos-a-nos-proprios-pleonasmo/33040) usado para enfatizar o objeto de *fazer*. Agora as alternativas (1) e (3) são extremas: a (1) é a que dá menos ênfase ao objeto, a (3) a que dá mais.

Na quarta também me parece melhor com a próclise, mas estou menos seguro:

> (4) Estas são as primeiras perguntas que eles têm de **nos** fazer.

Nos exemplos seguintes, a razão de não haver problema não é os verbos serem diferentes, é que já lá não temos o **que** nem qualquer outra coisa a pedir a próclise. Consideremos os seguintes exemplos, que usam **lavar** e **destruir** em construções idênticas à do título da pergunta:

> (5) A primeira coisa que nos disseram foi que temos **que lavar-nos**
>
> (6) A primeira coisa que nos disseram foi que temos **que destruir-nos**

Temos o mesmo problema de novo. E para o corrigir baste de novo passas da ênclise para a próclise:

> (5a) A primeira coisa que nos disseram foi que temos **que nos lavar**
>
> (6a) A primeira coisa que nos disseram foi que temos **que nos destruir**

A última frase da pergunta está incorreta por causa de **destruir a nós mesmos**: *destruir* pede um objeto direto: nós destruímos **uma casa**, não destruímos **a uma casa**. O mesmo se passa com *lavar*.

Comment: Peço desculpa só o feito depois de colocar a pergunta, mas entretanto editei-a a deixar claro que não me queria focar na questão da posição do clítico, que de resto é discutível (sim, a próclise é aqui mais comum mas apenas 4x no CETEMPúblico para ter de/que fazer).

Comment: Bem, talvez haja outra forma de as corrigir, mas eu prefiro a via mais simples. Acho que as minhas frases estão todas corretas.

Comment: Ah OK, então concluo que não achas nada de errado com "as perguntas que temos de nos fazer"? É de facto possível que tenha sido isso a levar-me a pensar que havia algo de errado com a frase.

Comment: Eu não vejo nada de errado com ela.

Comment: @Artefacto Estive a melhorar a argumentção.

Comment: Acho que a posição do pronome é de facto parte do problema, mas não todo. "perguntas que temos que nos fazer" parece-me já aceitável, mas não tão bom como "que fazer a nós próprios". Ainda pior: "perguntas que ele tem de se fazer". Em todo o caso, isso levou-me a procurar respostas no sítio errado, porque "nos" é objeto indireto nas 1as frases e direto nas 2as. A razão pq se pode omitir "nos" com fazer é porque o objeto indireto pede preposição, mas o direto em geral só é preposicionado se for usado de pleonasticamente (entre outras exceções que não vêm ao caso).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29182/discussion-between-jacinto-and-artefacto).

Answer (score 2):

Esta está correta:

> Estas são as primeiras perguntas que temos que fazer a nós próprios.

A transitividade de "fazer", neste caso, é a mesma que a do verbo "perguntar", ou seja, pede um objeto indireto. Já esta:

> Estas são as primeiras perguntas que temos que fazer-nos a nós próprios.

A transitividade está repetida, tanto pelo sufixo "-nos" quanto por "a nós próprios". Portanto, está incorreta.

> Estas são as primeiras perguntas que eles têm de fazer-nos.

Esta está correta, com ressalvas. O sufixo realiza a função de objeto direto ("a nós"), embora aqui [o uso de ênclise seja desencorajado](http://www.mundoeducacao.com/gramatica/proclise-mesoclise-enclise.htm). Uma forma mais gramaticalmente correta seria:

> Estas são as primeiras perguntas que eles têm de nos fazer.

Já estas estão ambas gramaticalmente incorretas, ou corretas com ressalvas:

> A primeira coisa que temos de fazer é lavar-nos.
>
> A primeira coisa que fizemos foi destruir-nos a nós mesmos.

Reescritas corretamente, seria:

> A primeira coisa que temos de fazer é nos lavar.
>
> A primeira coisa que fizemos foi destruir a nós mesmos.

Comment: Questão da posição do clítico à parte, não concordo com esta resposta. Não tem que ver com a repetição, "destruir-nos a nós mesmos" está com certeza correto (e posso arranjar fontes se quiseres). No entanto, tocaste num ponto que deve ser importante: na frase original, "a nós póprios" é complemento indireto, mas nas outras é direto.

Comment: Bom, então fico no aguardo de suas fontes. O emprego do sufixo + objeto indireto é pleonástico, a meu ver.

Comment: @Artefacto É pleonasmo, mas aceite. Vejam este [engarnarmo-nos a nós  próprios](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/enganarmo-nos-a-nos-proprios-pleonasmo/33040) tido por corretíssimo.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Não só é aceite como por vezes é necessário para desfazer ambiguades. Por exemplo, "Como são idênticas as formas do pronome recíproco e do reflexivo, pode haver ambiguidade com um sujeito plural. [...] Costuma remover-se a dúvida fazendo-se acompanhar tais pronomes de espressões reforçativas especiais. Assim: a) para marcar expressamente a acção rereflexiva, acrescenta-se-lhes, conforme a pessoa _a mim mesmo_, _a ti mesmo_, _a si mesmo_, etc.: Joaquim e António enganaram-se a si mesmos" (Breve Gramática do Português Comtemporâneo de Celso Cunha e Lindley Cintra.